# Typescript + React: Generic properties based on keys of other property object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Apologies for the somewhat confusing title.

I have a `React.FC` (duck-typed) in a `.tsx` file with a generic component:

```js
interface ITimeSeriesProps<PlotNames extends string> {

  /// map from keys to info about a plot
  plots: Record<PlotNames, Plot>,  // actual Plot type unimportant

  /// which ones to show on the plot
  show: PlotNames[]
}

const TimeSeries = <PlotNames extends string>(props: ITimeSeriesProps<PlotNames>) => {
  ...

  return <>
    ...
  </>
}
```

I can use it like this:

```js
<TimeSeries<"test">
  plots = {
    test: {...}    // correctly types this key
  }
  show: ["test"]   // correctly types this entry
>
</TimeSeries>
```

However,  I would prefer if I didn't have to specify the generic parameter `<"test">`, and that it was infered from the keys of the `plots` `Record` actual type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Use a `Record` type as the generic paramater rather than the keys by themselves:

```js
interface ITimeSeriesProps<PlotNames extends Record<string, Plot>> {
  plots: PlotNames,
  show: (keyof PlotNames)[]
}

const TimeSeries = <PlotNames extends Record<string, Plot>>(props: ITimeSeriesProps<PlotNames>) => {
  ...
}
```

Usage:

```js
<TimeSeries
  plots = {
    test: {...}    // correctly types this key
  }
  show: ["test"]   // correctly types this entry
>
</TimeSeries>
```